# Change time zone for tomcat

Tags: java, windows, timezone, tomcat8

I have downloaded Tomcat 8 and copied the unzipped folder in my required path.
I am using this tomcat as my server while running my web app.

1. When I access system default time zone using java time package, actually the time zone of what I get.
   Is it system's clock setting? Or is it tomcat's settings.
2. Where can I set time zone in tomcat.

Comment: ... But the answers are independent of operating system ...

Comment: It does not solve my problem. After reading those answers, do you think like it can solve my problem. :(

Comment: I have two questions there. First question can be answered right.

Comment: 1) By default, the Java Runtime Library uses the Operating Systems timezone. Tomcat doesn't do anything to change that. 2) Linked article has answer: Specify the JVM timezone by setting the value of `user.timezone` using the `-D` switch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Tomcat uses OS time settings.
2. Best place is to set environment variables is setenv.bat (setenv.sh) in tomcat bin directory. Use `set JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=GMT"` for windows or `export JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=GMT"` for linux. Also make sure that catalina.sh contains script to call setenv file. It should be there by default.

Comment: Is it possible to test whether tomcat time zone is set or not

Comment: Tomcat sets the time of jvm it's running, so you can use <%= new java.util.Date() %> in any jsp file. Or look into catalina.out in log directory it prints lot of information about server startup.

Comment: Ok. so the time I get in my Java program is based on what I set there. right? But from java, I always getting time based on my system clock settings

Comment: What you mean by from java? Is java in tomcat server or standalone? If on tomcat it should change, if standalone it will show OS time.

Comment: Means, In my system I have installed Java. I downloded tomcat and unzipped it in my D:\ drive. From eclipse I created a Java web project and right click on it. Run as --> Run on Server. Choose the tomcat from D:\ drive. Actually it is just a test API which will display the current time using LocalDateTime.now(). So the API displays my system time in browser.

Comment: To set time on eclipse you should configure it in Launch Configurations. In servers view of eclipse double click server, in window opened click to link Open Launch configuration, than in arguments tab append -Duser.timezone=GMT to end of the VM arguments.

Comment: Now it worked as expected. Thank you very much aios

Comment: Needles to say, if setenv.bat/(.sh) file does not exist, it should be created.